# iOS: Get displayed image size in pixels

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

In my app, I'm displaying an image of a rectangle from the assets library.  The image is 100x100 pixels.  I'm only using the 1x slot for this asset.

I want to display this image at 300x300 pixels.  Doing this using points is quite simple but I can't figure out how to get UIImageView to set the size in pixels.

Alternatively, if I can't set the size in pixels to display, I'd like to get the size in pixels that the image is being displayed.

I have tried using `.scale` on the UIImageView and UIImage instances, but it's always 1.  Even though I have set constraints to 150 and 300.

Comment: What do you want to do? Change ImageView to fit Image size? Scale image to fix image view or display image but not scale at all?

Comment: Show the image at the exact pixel size would be the best option.  So if the image is 100px by 100px, show it that size

Comment: set UIImageView to image.size.height;
image.size.width; I'm not try yet but maybe you net do something like UIImageView.frame.size.width = image.size.width/[UIScreen mainSreen].scale;

Comment: Tried that, but both the .size functions use points instead of pixels.  Also, the scale is always 1, not sure why.  With 100x100px image, set constraints for view to 150x150 and it scales it up, but reports .scale as 1 and .size as 100.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To get size in pixels of `UIImageView`:

```
let widthInPixels = imageView.frame.width * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
let heightInPixels = imageView.frame.height * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

To get size in pixels of `UIImage`:

```
let widthInPixels = image.size.width * image.scale
let heightInPixels = image.size.height * image.scale
```

Comment: Every image returns a scale of 1.0, as if all are squares. Any idea why?

Comment: you do not need to multiply image size with image scale the value will be the same because the scale is 1.0.

Comment: See the docs to understand what `scale` is. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale. Of course it's not always 1.0..

Comment: In Swift 5, use `UIScreen.main.scale`.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

> Take a Look [here](https://gist.github.com/FarisAlbalawi/40b3edd4f0db00e0f534c76af5533590)

```
// This extension to save ImageView as UImage
    extension UIView {
        func asImage() -> UIImage {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }
        }
    }

    // this extension to resize image 
    extension UIImage {
      func resizeImage(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let size = self.size
        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
        let newSize = widthRatio > heightRatio ?  CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio) : CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
      }
    }

    // This extension will display image with 300X300 pixels
    extension UIImage {
    func Size300X300() -> UIImage? {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
             imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
             imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
             let image = imageView.asImage()
             let newImage = image.resizeImage(targetSize: CGSize(width:300, height: 300))
             return newImage

          }
    }
```

> ```
>      let image = YOURIMAGE.Size300X300()
>      imageView.image = image!
> ```

Comment: Is there any way so I can maintain the size of the image too? Actually sticker size gets exceed over 100 KB.

Comment: Hey please update your sizes300x300 function because it not using any Image always return blank you need to add imageView.image = self.
Please verify and update your answer. thanks!

Comment: asImage function really help me a lot thank you so much!